# *ngIf on component class variable in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-components

I want to show loader when the flag variable is true and hide it when flag is false (two way data binding), but I dont know how to use *ngIf with component variable

***app.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../models/users.model';
import { UserServices } from '../../services/User.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-default',
    templateUrl: './default.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./default.component.css']
})
export class defaultComponent implements OnInit {
    public flag: boolean;
    userList: User[];
    constructor(private _service: UserServices) {
        this.flag = true;
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getData();
    }
    getData() {
        this.flag = true;
        this._service.loadData().subscribe( response => { this.userList = response; });
        this.flag = false;
    }
}
```

***default.component.html***

```
    <div *ngIf="flag == true" class="loader">Loading...</div>
    <div class="content">
        <!--my html-->
    </div>
```

I want to show loader div only when service is call and hide it after call compeleted.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: i want to show loader only when service is call and hide it after call compeleted.

Comment: Do you have something like `display:none;` in your `loader` class style? If so, remove that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getData` needs a bit of work:

```
getData() {
    this.flag = true;
    this._service.loadData().subscribe((response) => {
            this.userList = response;
            this.flag = false;
        });
}
```

And your component can get even simpler: get rid of the extra comparison, **ngIf** already works on booleans:

```
<div *ngIf="flag" class="loader">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: @UsfNoor Here, check out the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-loader?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2):

Set your flag to false when the response returns. Otherwise, you are setting it to false immediately:

```
getData() {
    this.flag = true;
    this._service.loadData().subscribe( response => { 
        this.userList = response;
        this.flag = false;
    });
}
```

Also, you don't need to check for `true` explicitly:

```
*ngIf="flag"
```

And if you like, you can initialize your flag when you declare it, instead of doing it in the constructor:

```
public flag: boolean = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the `this.flag = false;` into the `subscribe` block's  . Because of the javascript's async feature, your `flag` gets set to False before the backend call.

And a simple ngIf condition would be better.

```
<div *ngIf="flag" class="loader">Loading...</div>
```

---

```
getData() {
    this.flag = true;
    this._service.loadData().subscribe( response => { 
        this.userList = response;
        this.flag = false;
    });
}
```

**[PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/d5TDgMMj6Vwujbn8hN3N?p=preview)**

Comment: "Move the `this.flag = false;` into the `subscribe` block's `success`."
I cant get this, can you explain i?

Comment: sorry it's was typing mistake

Comment: let me create a sample for you

Comment: that will be greate favor for me

Comment: @UsfNoor : I have created a plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/d5TDgMMj6Vwujbn8hN3N?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162192/discussion-between-santosh-singh-and-usf-noor).